# Are there connected closed 4-manifolds admitting a regular Almost Lagrangian distribution, and which are not Lorentzian?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sg.symplectic-geometry, 4-manifolds

In the category of real differential manifolds, connected (of $ C ^ {\infty} $ class in the sequel), closed of dimension 4, is there any manifold admitting a regular Almost Lagrangian distribution and which are not Lorentzian?

Let $M $ be a real differential manifold closed (compact without boundary) of dimension 4.

By **Almost Lagrangian distribution** on $ M $, we mean a differentiable field of 2-plane $ L$  tangent to $ M$ defined everywhere over  $ M $. $ L $ is **regular** if the rank of $ L$ is 2 at any point of $ M$.

A **Lorentzian metric $ g $** on $ M $ is a differentiable field of non-degenerated quadratic form of signature (+++—) defined on the  tangent bundle $ TM$ of $ M $.
Two Lorentzian metrics $ g\text { and } g'$ on $ M$ are conformal if there is a smooth positive function $ f $ defined all over on $M $ such that $$ g'= f^ 2g. $$
This defines an equivalence relationship on the space of the Lorentzian metrics on $ M$.
A **conformal Lorentzian structure** on $ M $ is a class of equivalence for this relationship (when the space of the lorentzian metrics on $ M$ is non void; that is, when the euler characteristic of $ M $ is zero (for $ M$ orientable).)
Let $ (M, g) $ be a Lorentzian manifold of real dimension 4.
A **null frame** on an open set $U $ of $ M$ is a frame $(e_l) _l$ of $ M$ such that: $$g \text{ is positive definite on the span } \langle e_1,e_2\rangle,\; g(e_3, e_3) = g (e_4; e_4) = 0; g (e_3; e_4) = -2\text { on } U. $$
Considering a cover of $ (M, g) $ by $ g $-convex open sets, I think we can get a canonical Lagrangian distribution by taking at each point of $ M $, the 2-plane $ \langle e_1, e_2\rangle $  spanned by  $ e_1 \text { and } e_2 $.

The question I'm asking is whether the reciprocal is true; namely:         **Is the existence of a regular Almost Lagrangian distribution on the closed differential manifold $ M$ leads to the existence of a conformal Lorentzian structure on $M$**?

This question arises as I'm studying the existence and the stability of a Lorentzian metric $ g$ in its conformal class, or in general, when one want (I think), to study the existence of a conformal Lorentzian structure on a given manifold of real dimension 4.
Indeed, it seems to me that the solution to the problem of the formation, development and stability of the singularities in general relativity, as formulating in the epilogue of D. Christodoulou; "The Formation of Black Hole in General Relativity", and in general, the problem of the geometrization of a 4-differential manifold necessarily passes through:

- the study of the existence of a regular Almost Lagrangian distribution on any differential manifold of real dimension 4;
- when the manifold has a regular Almost Lagrangian distribution, study the link between this Lagrangian distribution and the existence of a conformal Lorentzian structure on the said manifold.
- More generally, study the singularities of an Almost Lagrangian distribution (eventually non regular) on a given class of manifold and the relationship between the singularities of the distribution and the geometry of a representative of the class of manifolds.
  The geometrization method is provided, for conformal Lorentzian manifolds, by the Einstein-Yang-Mills equations in a well-adapted gauge (space-temporal-lorenz; double null foliation) coupled with good conditions on the space of twistors of the manifolds (which we suppose orientable).

I think that by this procedure, one can attack with success, the stability of the family of Kerr solutions of vacuum Einstein field equations, in the lines given by S. Klainerman and J. Szeftel, "Kerr stability for small angular momentum" [arxiv:2104.11857v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.11857) (if I understood well what I learned at the introduction of that monograph).

All assistance, especially an example, even abstract, of a connected, closed manifold of real dimension 4, admitting a Lagrangian distribution on which there is no class of conformal Lorentzian metrics will be of the utmost importance (any reference is welcome, as is any indication of the demonstration method (cohomological, analytical, geometric...) with some details.)
Thank you heartfully for the time you will take to answer me and the answer you will give me.

Comment: Thanks Daniele Tampieri for the editing. I still have to master the task of well formatting.

Comment: I don't see why a 2-plane field is called Lagrangian.

Comment: You can't get a canonical Lagrangian distribution out of a conformal Lorentz metric. The conformal compactification of Minkowski space has no Lagrangian distribution invariant under its conformal isomorphisms.

Comment: Indeed, as @BenMcKay points out, the adjective 'Lagrangian' is usually only used with respect to a symplectic $2$-form on the manifold.  In any case, the manifold $S^2\times S^2$ clearly has a non-singular 2-plane field, but doesn't have a Lorentzian structure because its Euler characteristic is not zero.

Comment: In general I think, a lagrangian in a vector space is a subvector space of middle dimension.

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne:  Well, you are missing an important ingredient:  If the vector space has a symplectic structure, then a middle dimensional subspace $L$ is Lagrangian (with respect to the symplectic structure) if the defining $2$-form of the symplectic structure vanishes when pulled back to $L$.

Comment: So, I understand by lagrangian distribution, just a smooth section of grassmannian of middle dimension on the manifold. But as Pr @Robert Bryant put it, perhaps that, one can call such a distribution almost lagrangian, because I think that any such distribution much entail the existence of an almost complex structure on the manifold.

Comment: Thanks Pr @RobertBryant. So one have to show that the almost lagrangian distribution is associated to a almost symplectic form.

Comment: Thanks Pr @BenMckay. I will think about your example to better reformulate my question. Because I want to rule out the example such as direct product of two 2-manifolds.

Comment: In fact, perhaps that the notion of a **smooth non vanishing (regular?) bivector field** is more appropriate.

Comment: Proposition 37 (Chapter 5) in O'Neill's _Semi-Riemannian Geometry_ implies that, for closed manifolds, the existence of a Lorentzian structure is equivalent to the vanishing of Euler number. // Also, I don't see at all the connections you are drawing to general relativity: the solutions there are always emphatically **not** closed manifolds.

Comment: Good evening @WillieWong. You are right concerning G.R. But, by compactifying space-time one can work on a compact manifold and perhaps that one can with some good compactification even obtain a closed manifold.

Comment: The compactification can help bring study at infinity to finite distance if one has some control on the compactification process. I'm thinking about the compactification of the Euclidean or hyperbolic plan to get closed real surface. In any case, twistor space as used by Penrose (cf International Journal of Theoretical Physics, Vol. 1, No. 1 (1968), pp. 61-99) can help to see how compactification can be used to study the geometry of lorentzian manifold. Also cf all the work of C. LeBrun on the study of 4-riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Thanks M. @WillieWong.

Comment: You distinguish $L$ being a 2-plane and being of rank 2 (which you call regular); what do you mean by a 2-plane which is not of rank 2? How do you measure rank?

Comment: The study of the problem leads to what one could call "Almost Lagrangian Cohomology" and has strong connection with the theory of the Hyperbolic Exterior Differential Systems of Bryant-Griffiths-Hsu. 
Work in progress.

Comment: Hello @Ben McKay. Sincerely sorry for making clarification in response to your remarks now. By a 2-plane field, I understand a smooth distribution (that's, a vector sub-bundle of the tangent fiber bundle of the manifold) of rank 2 (that's of real dimension 2) defined on an open everywhere dense subset of the manifold. 
This field of 2-planes is regular when the open and dense subset coincides with the whole manifold. Thus, the rank refers to the actual maximum dimension of a generic fiber of the distribution.

Comment: Also the 2-plane is not of rang 2 when its domain of definition is a proper subset of the manifold.

Comment: In fact, the Twistor Space is just the arena where all the forces of the nature act; that's, the Twistor Space is the potential space realising the unification of all the forces, at least, for the four dimensional classical spacetime. The master's equation is surely, Eintein-almost-Hermitian-Higgs flow équations. Work still in progress.

Comment: The flow is given by a polarised(?) complex line bunde over the Twistor Space.
So, by following the philosophy of Bryant- Griffiths-Grosman-Hsu that is to work directly on the total space, we are looking for a almost complex manifold of real dimension 8 with a the problem of prescribing the first Chern class (the first two Chern classes?) solvable.
Under the hypothesis that the line bundle is polarisable and looking at a compactification and desingularization, perhaps one can manage to get a circle bundle over a Manifold of 'simple type'

Comment: (the first coming in my mind being a 7-differentiable (exotic?) sphere of "octonion's units"). In any case, the 7-simple manifold seems to me be strongly related to (perhaps is) the bundle of $Spin^c$-structures on the initial real 4 manifold.

Comment: Sadly, work still in progress. Hope that I will release a readable form of the work soon.
But as stopping (without some mild control) a flow of idea can be catastrophic, I can't make any promises. I just wish that this will free me from the obsession that all closed Lorentzian manifolds have some canonical presentation through a regular simple Riemann-Cartan Structure of parabolic type.

Comment: I think that Merkulov work on Twistor Connection will be an essential tools to conceive the right structure...

Comment: With the good test Manifold (initial smooth closed 4 manifold), the flow, which by conception is in fact the almost hermitian Ricci flow, allow without doubt (I think), to validate or invalidate, the existence of a smooth complex structure on the 6- euclidean standard sphere. In fact, there should be a way to associate to any Almost complex, connected and simply connected, closed manifold of real dimension 6, a characteristic connection on the canonical line bundle of the Twistor Space of a characteristic (that is, regular and minimal) closed lorentzian EYM 4 manifold

Comment: and the curvature of that characteristic line bundle should tell us All about the property of the almost complex 6 manifold. In this way, the signature of the almost hermitian 6 manifold is the characteristic spacetime (closed regular lorentzian 4 manifold which is EYM for some characteristic gauge group). In fact, I think that one can associate to any closed, connected, simply connected Almost complex manifold of any real dimension, a characteristic connection on the canonical line bundle of a closed pseudo Kahler manifold of real dimension 4 (pseudo Kahler being in the sense of Lichnerowicz)

Comment: I think that this circle of thought is there since a long date. However, I think that the way by which this association is made is more economical and more effective...

Comment: By using works of Lichnerowicz, Leray, Choquet-Bruhat, Cagnac, Chrusciel, H. Friedrich, Rendall, Dossa, Christodoulou, Klainerman, Martin-Garcia, J. Luk, we  conceive a geometric framework that we call Almost Hyperbolic Isotropic Structure (AHIS) which we think, can help to attack and even positively solve the topological geometry of real curves (and real algebraic curves in particular). We hope to post this soon. The structure must be equivalent or a slightly generalised Haefliger Structure. Work Almost finished.

Comment: Also work of Caciota, Nicolo, Rodnianski. That's on the Analysis of PDE side of the structure. On the geometic side, it's impossible to cite somebody because work of every geometer count. I can single just Riemann, Lie, Klein, Cartan, Chern

Comment: Imposing that M is closed is certainly very strong.
A more realistic framework would be that of a smooth "varifold with edge" equipped with a "non-degenerate" 2-form, this last condition being a kind of relaxation.

Comment: An Almost Isotropic Hyperbolic manifold is just a generalization of a manifold admitting an open book decomposition. An open book decomposition should correspond to the integrability of the Almost Isotropic Hyperbolic G-Structure determined by the Almost Isotropic Hyperbolic manifold. 
N.B. The concept of an Almost Isotropic Hyperbolic G-Structure was recently presented in the CIMPA school PDE and Calculus of Variations Benin 2022. 
We are currently working to take into account highly relevant remarks from a school organizer. We hope to produce the improved version soon.

Comment: A $G$-AIHS is just a kind of "framed" tractor space associated with a lorentzian conformal structure (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7559 and reference therein). It is also what one would call "Riemann-Cartan structure of real rank 2"; a "Riemann-Cartan structure of real rank $2m$" having to be a natural generalization for which the space of tractors is of dimension $n+2m$; this tractor space being associated with a pseudo-Riemannian conformal structure of real dimension $n$ and index $m$.

Comment: We can thus take advantage of all the heavy artillery forged by the "tractor's geometer's" to attack with a certain confidence, all the questions mentioned in certain comments above. 
Truly, there is nothing new under the sun...